# Does GitHub Actions replace ${{ secrets.NuGetAPIKey }} in nuget.config?

Tags: github, github-actions, github-package-registry

Github security does not allow storing Private Access Token in ClearTextPassword property of nuget.config. Basically, they disable the PAT. My question is, will the tag replacement of ${{ secrets.NuGetAPIKey }} take care of nuget.config also?

Note that without username & password in nuget.config, I couldn't publish my package to GitHub package (There is a tracking bug in GitHub for this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github replaces secrets only in the directory `.github/workflows`. I had a similar kind of requirement when I need to deploy the app on server using some keys. It's better to use environment variables with `env` tag in `yaml`. Refer the last deploy section of this public [gist](https://gist.github.com/lavish10/5f870660fb6b4c4ba01bac1ee4a48003)